# Event reservation system php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a small event-registration tool.
Users should be able to book multiple events at different times.

Example

```
Event1
    Time1 09:00 - 10:00 | Max Participants 12
    Time2 11:00 - 12:00 | Max Participants 9

Event2
    Time1 09:00 - 10:00 | Max Participants 6
    Time2 11:00 - 12:00 | Max Participants 9
```

I think I need the tables "events", "reservation" and "reservation-in-progress".
But I'm not sure how to structure these.

My Idea:

**events**

```
event_id | host_id | date_of_event | title | description | time_1 | max_participants_1 | time_2 | max_participants_2
```

**reservation**

```
reservation_id | user_id | date_of_reservation | event_1 | time_1 | event_2| time_2
```

**reservation-in-progress**

```
reservation-in-progress_id | user_id | date_of_reservation | event_1 | time_1 | event_2| time_2 | time_end_of_blocked_reservation
```

Comment: What is the reason for reservation-in-progress? Also, do you want to register the users/participants aswell?

Comment: To prevent double booking of the same time slot, while the booking is in progress and the user selects his events and times.

Answer (score 0):

your idea is right but no need to take second table reservation-in-progress you can simply add status field in the events or reservation table so you can mark status as in progress.

Thanks